# What is that song Ripley sings while buckling-in the space-suit in Alien?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979, music-identification

Towards the end, when Ripley finally ...

> blows it out of the damned airlock!

She mutters a little song that seems to go

```
   .... you .... are ... (my) ... lucky ..... star ....  
   .... lucky-lucky-lucky ....
```

or something.

What is that song?

Comment: A hint: http://www.quora.com/Alien-1979-movie/What-is-Ellen-Ripley-singing-to-herself-in-the-last-scene-of-the-film-Alien

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is it:

*You are my lucky star* from Broadway Melody, 1936.

Easier to follow the lyrics in this earlier recording:

And this version actually has the oft-omitted "Verse":

Answer (score 5):

Debbie Reynolds - You Are My Lucky Star.  I very much believe it's from the film "Singing in the Rain", Hollywood, from just after WW2.  Ripley repeats it, as one would do, to concentrate on the job at hand rather than have her mind freeze or frazzle from the terror implicit in her situation.

Lovely refrain and obviously someone believes it'll stand the test of time.